# Problem Importing to MYSQL with Pandas: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, unicode

I am trying to import multiple csv's in a dataframe at one time using pandas to_sql, to a MySQL database. After creating the engine, I am running the following:

```
folder_path = (file_path)
os.chdir(folder_path)
for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if '.csv' in file:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory = False)
        table_name = str(file.strip('.csv'))
        df.to_sql(table_name, con = engine, if_exists = 'replace')
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to "

Even when I try using the import wizard to uload that specific table the error is appearing on, it only imports 50 out of the 42,000 records.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a sample of your csv data? My assumption, without much information is that could be related with the way your `CSV` data is in the file. Check line 49, 50 and 51 of the `CSV`

Comment: The data is from this kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/mrmorj/dataset-of-songs-in-spotify    . The error is appearing from the first file, genres-v2. There are definitely lines which I see that don't contain UTF-8, however they aren't around 50. Any advice on how to quickly delete all rows which contain non-utf-8 characters, before import?

Comment: Always specify the encoding (e.g. in `read_csv`). Do not trust Python will find it for you (and unfortunately WIndows still use unpredictable defaults)

Comment: @shuaf98 which file are you using? You need to give me a bit more than that for me to be able to help :)

Comment: Rui, the file is the genres_v2 file that is on the kaggle link I posted. Giacoma, the the encoding is specified currently as UTF-8. Is there a different encoding that would work instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the "correct" way of doing it, but I found a regex which selects only characters in UTF-8, removing the rest, for each field in the dataframe:

```
df.replace({r'[^\x00-\x7F]+':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Ideally though, I would like to keep the non UTF-8 characters, if there are any other solutions.